# Hide sub div on second time click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've following script to show & hide subdiv on subsequent clicks but somehow it doesn't hide subdiv on second click.
Here's the code:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
   $('#floatcategory').append("<div class='floatbutton'
   id='float_"+categories[k][0]+"'>" +categories[k][1]+"</div>");
   $('#floatcategory').append("<div id='"+categories[k][0]+"_"+products[l][0]+"'>"
   +products[l][1]+"</div>");
});
 $('.floatbutton').live('click',function() {
    var floatidl=$(this).attr('id');
    var floatid=floatidl.substr(6);
    if ($('#'+floatidl'').hasClass("clicked-once")){
        $('[id^="'+floatid+'_"]').hide();
        $('#'+floatidl'').removeClass("clicked-once");
    }
    else {
        $('[id^="'+floatid+'_"]').show();
        $('#'+floatidl'').addClass("clicked-once");
    }
});
</script>
```

I'm using jQuery version 1.6. It doesn't hide the div. Can anyone help?

Comment: So what happens? The user clicks `.floatbutton` twice and some div.. `#floatidl`? is supposed to hide on second click?

Comment: where is element with `#floatidl` in your code?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's what it supposes to do.

Comment: Sorry @Unknown, please look at the code it was `$('#'+floatidl'')`

Comment: do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/aras7/mVHa7/1/ or maybe like this http://jsfiddle.net/aras7/mVHa7/4/?

Comment: Yes that's what I want but I have dynamic ids, like particular category id & product id.

Comment: @user3664667 like this  jsfiddle.net/aras7/mVHa7/1 ?

Comment: Yes @Andres like `jsfiddle.net/aras7/mVHa7/1`, that's what I want & that's what I've used in my code as well. but somehow it's not working in my case (dynamic ids)

Comment: I think you need this http://jsfiddle.net/aras7/mVHa7/6/, tell me if so to explain in an answer

Comment: Yes @Andres but that's now working in my case, I'm adding class like this `$('#'+floatidl'').addClass("clicked-once");` is there any problem with this? I'm passing value of floadidl to the div id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (for older jquery versions - < v1.7):

```
$('.floatbutton').live('click',function() {
    var floatidl=$(this).attr('id');
    var floatid=floatidl.substr(6);
    if ($('#'+floatid).hasClass("clicked-once")){
        $('[id^='+floatid+']').hide();
        $('#'+floatid).removeClass("clicked-once");
    }
    else {
        $('[id^='+floatid+']').show();
        $('#'+floatid).addClass("clicked-once");
    }   
});
```

or

```
$(document).delegate('.floatbutton','click',function() {
        var floatidl=$(this).attr('id');
        var floatid=floatidl.substr(6);
        if ($('#'+floatid).hasClass("clicked-once")){
            $('[id^='+floatid+']').hide();
            $('#'+floatid).removeClass("clicked-once");
        }
        else {
            $('[id^='+floatid+']').show();
            $('#'+floatid).addClass("clicked-once");
        }   
    });
```

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (for new jquery versions - >= 1.7):

```
$(document).on('click','.floatbutton',function() {
            var floatidl=$(this).attr('id');
            var floatid=floatidl.substr(6);
            if ($('#'+floatid).hasClass("clicked-once")){
                $('[id^='+floatid+']').hide();
                $('#'+floatid).removeClass("clicked-once");
            }
            else {
                $('[id^='+floatid+']').show();
                $('#'+floatid).addClass("clicked-once");
            }   
        });
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Yes that's where I was making mistake, so stupid, thanks a lot buddy :)

Comment: you are right, it is better to use newer versions of jquery and `$(document).on('click',...`

Answer (score 1):

when you use

```
$('.floatbutton').live('click',function() {
```

it will only work for divs which are **not** added dynamically

You should use something like this to handle dynamically added objects:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click",".floatbutton",function(){
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aras7/mVHa7/6/